# MySql and Entity Framework in VS2012 - cannot select provider

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector

I am trying to write a data-access layer for an existing MySQL database using EntityFramework 5 in .Net 4.5 with Visual Studio 2012.  I've run the following nuget commands in the Visual Studio 2012 nuget console to get started:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package MySQL.Data.Entities
```

However, when I attempt to add an Ado.Net Entity Data Model and "Generate from database", and then 'New Connection', the MySQL provider is not listed in the "Data Source" listbox, nor is it available in the 'Data Provider" combobox.

Am I missing something simple?  I'm writing a class-library.. but I've tried these same steps in a Console Application with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received this direction from Gabriela Martinez:

> The nuget packages for MySQL are from someone in the community and are
>   not fully supported.  To get the Visual Studio interface working
>   properly with Entity Framework, it is recommended that developers
>   install the MSI of the MySQL connector tools.

After that install, I was able to begin running with MySQL in Entity Framework with no problems.